# placing movie clips around a 24hr clock face (as2) - time management

Tags: actionscript-2, flash

I am currently working on a project to plot the activities of my day out by placing them around a 24 hr clock face. the final out come of this is a time management app that allows you to find spaces in your day that could be used more proficiently; however; I have hit a bit of a snafu and that is assigning each movie clip (each of which represents an activity) to its correct place of on the clock face.

I am using an XML file to pull the times from and the calculation of the angle where the movie clip should be placed on the clock is done in relation to a central movie clip.

for (i = 0; i < TimeSheet.length; i++)      {
            var counter = i + 1;

```
        sortXML(TimeSheet);
    }
}
```

};
function sortXML(TimeSheet){

```
var activity = TimeSheet[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
var description = TimeSheet[i].firstChild.nextSibling.childNodes;
var HrStart = TimeSheet[i].firstChild.nextSibling.nextSibling.childNodes;
var MinStart = TimeSheet[i].firstChild.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.childNodes;
var HrEnd = TimeSheet[i].firstChild.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.childNodes;
var MinEnd = TimeSheet[i].firstChild.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.childNodes;

var place = TimeSheet[i].firstChild.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.childNodes;
var creativity = TimeSheet[i].firstChild.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.childNodes;
var usefulness = TimeSheet[i].firstChild.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.childNodes;
var enjoyment = TimeSheet[i].firstChild.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.childNodes;
var focus = TimeSheet[i].firstChild.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.childNodes;



category = TimeSheet[i].nodeName;


HourStart = parseInt(HrStart, 10);
MinuteStart = parseInt(MinStart, 10);
HourEnd = parseInt(HrEnd, 10);
MinuteEnd = parseInt(MinEnd, 10);

Creativity = parseInt(creativity, 10);
Focus = parseInt(focus, 10);
Usefulness = parseInt(usefulness, 10)

var TimeSpent = ((HourEnd*60)+MinuteEnd) - ((HourStart*60)+MinuteStart) ;
//var ActivityMinutes = (HourStart*60)+MinuteStart;
var TimeStart = (HourStart*60)+MinuteStart;
var BobPlacement = ((TimeStart/1440)*360) // where the bob gets blaced on the circle
//var BobPlacement = (360/1440)*TimeStart;

//var radius = 150 + Usefulness;
var radius = 200 + (Usefulness/2);
var xcenter = _root.bobCentral._x;
var ycenter = _root.bobCentral._y;
var degree = (BobPlacement + 180)*-1;;
var radian;

radian = (degree/180)*Math.PI;
newBob._x = xcenter+Math.cos(radian)*radius;
newBob._y = ycenter-Math.sin(radian)*radius;




/*trace("-----------------------------------");
trace("category = "+category);
trace("activity = " + activity);
trace("Description = " + description);
trace("time start = " + HourStart + ":" + MinuteStart);
trace("time end = " + HourEnd + ":" + MinuteEnd);
trace("Duration of activity = "+TimeSpent);

trace("place = "+ place);
trace("creativity = "+ creativity);
trace("usefulness = "+ usefulness);
trace("enjoyment = "+ enjoyment);
trace("focus = "+ focus);
trace("Time Started = "+ TimeStart);
trace("palce on circle = "+ BobPlacement);
*/

dupeMC(TimeSheet, category, activity, description, HourStart, MinuteStart, TimeSpent, Creativity, Focus, Usefulness);
```

}
function dupeMC(TimeSheet, category, activity, description, HourStart, MinuteStart, TimeSpent, Creativity, Focus, Usefulness){

```
bob.duplicateMovieClip("bob"+i, i);

newBob = eval("bob"+i);
```

Any help would be much appreciated

I apologies in advance if the way I have put this question forward is confusing in any way.

Comment: and where exactly does the "snafu" happen? it's very daunting to prepare the movieclips and everything so we can actually compile your code. perhaps you could 1) write what happens instead of expected behavior 2)point out specific parts of code